# Is there a way to have siblings with different children in Eloquent eager loading?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to build an eloquent query in Laravel 5.7 that will return a collection with the sibling of 'traveler' with different 'ticket' collections based on a conditional of a column value

I tried to call two ->with relationships to the parent 'order' using two 'traveler' chains with different where statements on the traveler. When I do this, it seems that one overwrites the other instead of adding an additional collection entry along side in the 'travelers' collection.

Tables

traveler: override

traveler_ticekts: traveler_id | package_id | info1_id | info2_id | info3_id

packages: info1_id | info2_id | info3_id

The 'info' field value on 'traveler_tickets' are not necessary if they chose a pre-set package - otherwise if the traveler record is set to 'override' it will add them directly to the ticket as options

I am trying to maximize this relationship performance and would like it in one statement if it makes sense, or the next best alternative.

Thank you in advance!

```
$order_data = Orders::with([    
'travelers' => function ($q){
    $q->with(
           'ticket.package.info1',
           'ticket.package.info2',
           'ticket.package.info3'
    )->WhereNull('override');
},
    'travelers' => function ($q){
        $q->with(
           'ticket.info1',
           'ticket.info2',
           'ticket.info3'               
        )->where('override', 1);
}
])->find($id);
```

I would expect that I would get a collection where the two traveler chains are all still in the same collection with alternate child paths set per traveler record, but I only receive a single chain, whichever is last (I'm guessing because it gets overwritten instead of added to)

Comment: Yes, that's because you are overriding it using the same array key which should be unique, you can use something like `with(['something as x' => func, 'something as y' => func])`

Comment: I duplicated the 'travelers' model method from 'orders' and renamed it to 'traveler_override'. now I have two separate collections - how can I merge these with laravel so it is Orders->Travelers in the collection and drop the travelers_override?

Comment: Also, is the above method I am using the most efficient? I can merge these two together without much overhead I would assume, but what about query load on the initial query?

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear for me so I cannot give you an advice on that, but anyway since it returns a collection then you can merge these easily `$Travelers = $order_data->travelers->merge($order_data->travelers_override);`

Comment: Does this method create additional DB queries that can be avoided by another method?

Comment: Thank you, the merge did extract the elements in to a single collection. How would I merge the result back into the main collection for a single 'travelers' child, and then remove the 'travelers_override' collection? I have been trying and cannot get the syntax to work correctly `$order_data->travelers->push($merge);` This outputs a strange hierarchy with duplicates